# Overload resolution, order of defined functions and templates

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> func(T value) {
    std::cout << "T\n";
    return func(static_cast<int64_t>(value));
}

bool func(int64_t value) {
    std::cout << "int64_t\n";
    return true;
}

int main() {
    func(1);
}
```

It causes infinite recursion. However, swapping the definition order of these two functions (if `bool func(int64_t value)` defined before template one) helps to avoid this issue.

Why is that? Does order of function overloads matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler is parsing the first function (the template) it doesn't know anything about the second overload of `func`. Parsing is done top-to-bottom of the source file.

That's the reason you need to have declarations of symbols before you use them. That also means just having a *declaration* of `bool func(int64_t);` at the top would solve your problem.

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to explain why `func` is chosen at parsing-time, rather than instantiation-time.

Answer (score 5):

> Does order of function overloads matter?

It doesn't change the result of overload resolution, but the result of [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup); which happens before overload resolution.

(emphasis mine)

> For a name used in global (top-level namespace) scope, outside of any function, class, or user-declared namespace, **the global scope before the use of the name is examined**:

That means for the invocation of `func` inside the templated `func`, only itself could be found (and be added to the overload set), the non-template version won't be considered at all.

As you have seen, if you change their declaration order, both `func` would be found and considered at the following overload resolution, and the non-template `func` is selected (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

> Does order of function overloads matter?

The order of overloads does matter in the sense that if the overload set is called before a potential overload is declared, that not-yet declared function doesn't take part in the overload resolution.

The order of overloads declared before the function call does not matter.