# may I ask why the following code fails to compile?

Tags: c++

may I ask why the following code fails to compile? **I know how to fix it**, but it's not clear why here is wrong?

```
#include <time.h>

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct log_type_default_forward : std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool log_type_default_forward_v =
    log_type_default_forward<T>::value;

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(
    std::remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(
    std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
namespace xx {
struct Abc {};

struct Bcd : Abc {};
}  // namespace xx

template <typename T>
void f(T&& t) {
    LogTypeForward<T>(t);
}

template <typename T>
struct log_type_default_forward<
    T, std::enable_if_t<
           std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>*, const xx::Abc*> > >
    : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>*, const xx::Abc*>,
                 const T&>
LogTypeForward(const T& t) noexcept {
    cout << "xx" << endl;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    xx::Abc abc;
    f(abc);
    xx::Bcd bcd;
    f(bcd);
    return 0;
}
```

From the compilation error, log_type_default_forward works, but LogTypeForward does not:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void f(T&&) [with T = xx::Abc&]':
<source>:53:6:   required from here
<source>:34:22: error: no matching function for call to 'LogTypeForward<xx::Abc&>(xx::Abc&)'
   34 |     LogTypeForward<T>(t);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:16:54: note: candidate: 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&)'
   16 | std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:60,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/functional:49,
                 from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = xx::Abc&]':
<source>:16:54:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&) [with T = xx::Abc&]'
<source>:34:22:   required from 'void f(T&&) [with T = xx::Abc&]'
<source>:53:6:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits:2514:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, xx::Abc&>'
 2514 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In instantiation of 'void f(T&&) [with T = xx::Abc&]':
<source>:53:6:   required from here
<source>:22:54: note: candidate: 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&&)'
   22 | std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>: In instantiation of 'void f(T&&) [with T = xx::Bcd&]':
<source>:55:6:   required from here
<source>:34:22: error: no matching function for call to 'LogTypeForward<xx::Bcd&>(xx::Bcd&)'
   34 |     LogTypeForward<T>(t);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:16:54: note: candidate: 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&)'
   16 | std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:60,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/functional:49,
                 from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = xx::Bcd&]':
<source>:16:54:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&) [with T = xx::Bcd&]'
<source>:34:22:   required from 'void f(T&&) [with T = xx::Bcd&]'
<source>:55:6:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits:2514:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, xx::Bcd&>'
 2514 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In instantiation of 'void f(T&&) [with T = xx::Bcd&]':
<source>:55:6:   required from here
<source>:22:54: note: candidate: 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&&)'
   22 | std::enable_if_t<log_type_default_forward_v<T>, T&&> LogTypeForward(
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

The purpose of this code is to perform additional processing on specific types, so that the user can customize the behavior of forwarding.

Comment: `f` needs to be moved after the template specialisations that it is using

Comment: i know how to fix it, but why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55119673/5376789